# Root element must be named &apos;request&apos; Workbench Error

Tags: apex, rest-api, json, xml

I have below rest resource class in which i am creating account. From workbench i am using RestExplorer to test this class. I am passing the data in JSON format which is working fine.

If I pass XML data as below:

```
<Account>
    <AccountName>TestXML</AccountName>
    <Phone>1234567890</Phone>
    <Website>wwww.siyet.com</Website>
</Account>
```

I get an error like below:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <Errors>
>     <Error>
>         <errorCode>XML_PARSER_ERROR</errorCode>
>         <message>Root element must be named &apos;request&apos;</message>
>     </Error>
> </Errors>
> ```

Here is my endpoint:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Account/*')
global with sharing class MyRestResource {

      @HttpPost

        global static String doPost(String name,String phone, String website) {   
            Account account = new Account();
            account.Name = name;
            account.phone = phone;
            account.website = website;
            insert account;
            return account.Id;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap the request body inside `<request></request>` element. Also, the names of the Apex parameters matter, although the order doesn’t. In your example, your method expects `name`, `phone`, and `website` as three parameters directly under root not wrapped inside Account element.

For your example, valid request body should look like this. Hope this will work for you.

```
<request>
    <name>TestXML</name>
    <phone>1234567890</phone>
    <website>wwww.siyet.com</website>
</request>
```

Check [Salesforce Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm) for more details.